# TableAdapter Query with optional WHERE paramerter

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, tableadapter

I am trying to create a TableAdapter query with an optional WHERE parameter. 
This is my query:

```
    SELECT Productos.Categoria, Productos.Subcategoria, Productos.Nombre,
 Productos.Marca, Productos.Descripcion, Proveedores.Nombre AS Proveedor, Precios.Precio

    FROM Precios, Productos, Proveedores
    WHERE Precios.Producto_ID = Productos.ID AND Precios.Proveedor_ID =
 Proveedores.ID AND Proveedores.Nombre = ?
```

I would like "***Proveedores.Nombre = ?***" to be optional or if ? = null or nothing, the query does not filter by ***Proveedores.Nombre***

I have tried this:

```
(Proveedores.Nombre =@PNombre OR @PNombre = NULL)
```

But I have got an error:

> Generated SELECT statement:
>
> Error in WHERE clause near '@'.
>
> Unable to parse the query text

Thank you very much for you help,

Regards

Andres

EDIT:
I ma in a windows form project. I am using a DataSource - DataSet linked to my access database. So to create FillBy() and GetData() I use a table-adapter which was automatically created when I inserted the DataSource to my WindowsForm.
This is the method created liked to the GetData() I am using:

```
public virtual DB_ProvProd2DataSet.ProductosDataTable GetDataByTodo(string Nombre) {
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[5];
    if ((Nombre == null)) {
        throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("Nombre");
    }
    else {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(Nombre));
    }
    DB_ProvProd2DataSet.ProductosDataTable dataTable = new DB_ProvProd2DataSet.ProductosDataTable();
    this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    return dataTable;
}
```

Where this.CommandCollection[5] = the query and this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0] is the input related to the '?' of the query.

I hope this helps!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try assing it to a local variable:
string tmp= @PNombre

(Proveedores.Nomber==tmp || tmp == null)

Comment: It could be silly question, but where should I declare string tmp= @PNombre ?

Comment: Before doing your query.

Comment: I cannot, I am using Query wizard from a DataSource - DataSet. I have added a bit of more information to my post.

Comment: At this point I would rather load a dataset and filter the dataset on what i need to see